# Wifi works on windows but not on linux why?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, compaq-laptop

After using Linux in virtual environments, I got pleased and installed Linux on my main machine, a [Compaq CQ45 laptop](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c03377576) which has an [Ralink RT5390R 802.11bgn](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ralink%20RT5390R%20802.11bgn%20Wi-Fi%20Adapter&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS804US804&oq=Ralink%20RT5390R%20802.11bgn%20Wi-Fi%20Adapter) Wi-Fi Adapter. WiFi connects, but there is no access.

I've tried many distros like Ubuntu, Manjaro, Zorin, Elementary OS, Mint, and with different desktop environments.

Some of them don't even let me connect and some just shows the question mark, so I have to move back to Windows to use Wifi.

I am a beginner who wants to get into the Linux world. what can I do?

I  tried some fixes I saw from YouTube, like changing the `resolv.conf` file with `8.8.8.8` as shown in the video.

this is the result i got running the lspci -knn | grep... command

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:539b]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RT5390R 802.11bgn PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:18ed]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: In a virtual environment you aren't using the real hardware and network connection for the VM is typically provided by a virtual Ethernet regardless of the actual device in the host.  Your question is then quite confusing.

Comment: If actually installed then you are missing drivers for that specific Wi-Fi device.

Comment: I mean to say in windows operating system it worked fine but in many linux distro it didnt work .either it didnt connect or has no access.there is nothing about the vm.

Comment: Where can i get the drivers and install in linux as i dont know any thing about it

Comment: @Sudru - can you post (add to your question) the make/model # of the WiFi adapter?

Comment: @ajgringo619 its Ralink RT5390R 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter  my laptop is compaq cq45 4 gb of ram

Comment: (from a simple web search): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QY46JReJ1s

Comment: @ajgringo619 I will surely try this plz suggest me a distro i am a  absolute beginner and a student as well ..

Comment: @Sudru - try Linux Mint.

Comment: @Sudru You may need to install additional firmware to make the WiFi work (IIRC Ralink is quite well-supported). I need to get to work soon, but tomorrow I can fire up my Linux Mint VM to see which packages are required for that. You then need to download that via Ethernet.

Comment: In Linux, please run this in a terminal `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` then click [edit] and add the results to your question. Also, there are many different Compaq CQ45 models; please look on the serial number sticker and add the model number you see there to your question with [edit].

Comment: Changing the DNS only works if you can ping an address like `8.8.8.8`, but can't ping `google.com`. Being unable to ping domains means your domain resolver does not work. However, changing `/etc/resolve.conf` is pointless, since that files gets regenerated every boot. You need to change the interface script instead. The first thing you need to do, is to make sure the WiFi chip is properly installed. You can do that by running `ip a ` and see if a device akin to `wlan0` is active and if you can connect to a hotspot.

Comment: @Robidu now i recently installed linux mint  mate but it has a very weak signal and the internet sometimes work and and sometime dont i am at a distance of 1 metre away from my home router but it shows very weak signal can you help me plzz,..

Answer (score 3):

Go to the manufacturer's Support site for your make and model of machine and get the Linux driver for the Wi-Fi card and then install it in your Linux system.

Comment: How can i download and install drivers in linux as i dont know any thing about linux   which distro should i choose as i am a student and a absolute beginner to linux

Comment: Your computer support site should have Linux Drivers. Go there and check.  If there are none for you computer, get a USB Wireless card (Best Buy or like) and be sure it says it has Linux drivers on the box. Then once you have drivers, put them on a USB key and follow your Linux distribution instructions for installing software